# How to add bcc for forgot password emails in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I want add bcc for forgot password email in magento 2.

When i checked the code - \vendor\magento\module-customer\Controller\Account\ForgotPasswordPost.php in execute method we have this

```
try {
       $this->customerAccountManagement->initiatePasswordReset(
                    $email,
                    AccountManagement::EMAIL_RESET
                );
}
```

How can i add Bcc for this mail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this function **sendEmailTemplate** on **vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/EmailNotification.php** ,and try to override and add BCC email in **$bccEmail** like below.

```
$transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId)
    ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId])
    ->setTemplateVars($templateParams)
    ->setFrom($from)
    ->addTo($email, $this->customerViewHelper->getCustomerName($customer))
    ->addBcc([$bccEmail])
    ->getTransport();
```